# "Властьпредержащие": разговорное?

Tags: этимология

Собственно, о слове "властьпредержащие". Почему "предержащие"? Или это разговорно-ироничное выражение, относящееся к "слугам народа"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это выражение (а не одно слово) из Библии (церковно-славянский текст). В Послание апостола Павла к римлянам, гл. 13, ст. 1—5 говорится о повиновении властям: "Всяка душа властем предержащим да повинуется. Несть бо власть аще не от Бога". 
В переводе на русский язык "предержащий" означает «главный», «верховный», «высший» (от древнеславянского глагола "пръдрьжати", который означает «править, возглавлять»). Соответственно само это словосочетание переводится как "верховная власть" и должно бы произноситься именно как "власти (а не "власть") предержащие", но этимологию выражения уже основательно подзабыли и первое слово начали употреблять уже в именительном падеже. 
Иронически, как правило при использовании публицистического стиля речи, так говорят о руководстве, правительстве, администрации, начальстве всякого рода.

Comment: >и первое слово начали употреблять уже в именительном падеже.   
  
Вы не путаете? В чем неправильность употребления слова "власти" или "власть" в именительном падеже? 
Ошибка возникает как раз в силу рассогласования падежей, когда "предержащих" остается в винительном, а склоняется только "власть"/"власти". Это является следствием переосмысления "власти - какие?" (сравните "власти верховные")  на "предержащие что" (держащие власть).

Answer (score 0):

Я не собираюсь быть судьёй в споре о том, прямая ли эта "цитата" из Евангелий или же что-то новообразованное.

Но совершенно очевидно, что тут не "предержащие что", а "власти какие". Дело в том, что есть еще и "рука [власть] предержащая", тут, слава богу, еще не додумались до "предержащей руки".

Статья по ссылке grumant'a - путана и излишне эмоциональна, но в ней есть неопровержимые ссылки на словари.

А вообще вопрос древний как мир. Но, полагаю, процесс переосмысления зашел настолько далеко, что он встаёт снова и снова.

> ... я всегда воспринимала в этом выражении "предержащие" как эпитет "властей", поэтому "власть предержащие" кажутся неправильным выражением.

Уточните, если не трудно. Вас смущает единственное число или сам оборот?
"Власти предержащие" - нормально? Если да, то просклоняйте, пожалуйста.
В родительном - "Властей предержащих" или "Власть предержащих"?

Comment: "Властей предержащих". Я согласна, что "власти какие", поэтому и называю второе слово эпитетом. По-моему, наши с Вами мнения полностью совпадают.  
А вот считать другой вариант - "власть предержащие", как @Fuchoin Kazuki, ироническим переосмыслением, я как-то не могу. Нет соответствующего языкового опыта. Выражение воспринимаю просто как выспреннее и нарочито книжное, а не как ироническое.

Comment: Я думаю, нельзя банальными запретами мешать развитию смыслов и нюансов в подобных фразеологических конструкциях. Кому оно мешает? *Власти предержащие* - *власти властвующие*, обладающие реальной силой. *Власть предержащие* - упивающиеся своей властью; они ей обладают со вкусом и дивидендами. Кто-то власть предержит, кто-то жизнь живет, а кто-то просто - вино пирует!))) Прошу оставить словотворчество и развитие языка на самотек! Худшее отсеется, лучшее войдет в золотой фонд.

Comment: Да ради бога! Я просто сказала, что мне такое употребление не встречалось. Да и вообще выражение редкое, так что не о чем спорить!

Answer (score 0):

Дорогие коллеги,

Очевидно смешение понятий определения предмета обсуждения, а именно, определяющего
существительного.

Совершенно правомерно и грамматически правильно употреблять оба варианта, следуя
при этом правилам и замечаниям, указанным в скобках:

1. власть предержащие ("власть" только единст.число и не склоняется,
                           "предержащие" склоняется по всем падежам - здесь роль 
                           существительного определяет слово "предержащие")
2. власти предержащие (здесь существительное слово "власти" и здесь оба слова во
                           множ.числе и оба склоняются по всем падежам)

Comment: >Совершенно правомерно и грамматически правильно   
  
Совершенно очевидно, что никаких аргументов в пользу этого мнения у Вас нет, даже элементарных ссылок на источники.   
А вопрос числа - глубоко второстепенный. Встречается и "в руце/власти предержащей" и " в руках/властях предержащих". А вот "в предержащих руку/власть" - это уже нонсенс.     
(+)
Вы вместо деклараций, просклоняли бы, как оно Вам видится. Сдается мне, что Вы суть вопроса не уловили. Она в том, можно ли трактовать оборот как "[лица] власть (руку) предержащие" или же только как "власть (рука) ***предержащая***".